# How do one use Mobile_Detect.php for a web form?

Tags: php, html, css, browser-detection

I am currently a beginner developing a web form and I am stuck on the mobile support stuff and I came across this php code:  [Mobile_Detect.php](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php)

How do I use it on make my [form](https://github.com/ngeshlew/responsive-html5-web-form)?

Comment: So what exactly is your question? There are examples at GitHub which you can use for your code (https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/wiki/Code-examples). What do you want to do with the output of Mobile_Detect? If your question is related to the styling of your form take a look at responsive Design and Media Querys!

Comment: the styling is the issue @Daniel

Comment: Check also this [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/) which runs an `if` statement and is really effective for many coding langs.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have for your form at the moment, plus a description of what you are having trouble with? In Stack Overflow terms, this question is rather too broad to answer at the moment.

Comment: @halfer he postet a link to his GIT Repo of the formular

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. We ask posters to make questions mostly (if not entirely) self-contained, thus since the question completely relies on that link, it is susceptible to link breakage, and in that event will not be of use to future readers. A supplementary link to a repo or a fiddle is fine, but as I say we need to have the basis of the problem in a code block here.

Comment: Okay, am new in Stackoverflow. My code is 199 lines, any advise on how I put it here?

Comment: @marios the problem is I have no idea how to embed it on my index file even after downloading the codes from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com

Comment: @user3635374 See my answer - that should explain how to embed the code. And please don't paste all the codes you have! If your question is related to the PHP part we don't need/want to see CSS and large HTML parts.

Comment: From my own research, media queries are the best. My main question is, what HTML elements need to be edited for the layout to be responsive to the screen size?

Comment: If you use php then only thing you have to do is to include the file like `include 'detector.php';` exactly were you want the filtering to run. This code in the detector file uses an if statement. It runs its script and if this returns true then redirects the user with `header();` method to a mobile friendly page. You could modify this last line and return a custom redirection etc

Comment: @marios then that means I will have to have another page specific for the type of device supported?

Comment: Yes that's how this works. You are not forced to do that. You could just use the `if()` statement to check if the script detects mobile devices and return whatever you like by replacing the `header();` redirection. The redirection happens on the very end of the script. This can be changed to a custom response. All that matters for you is the `if()` check that is really very effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an styling issue there are different ways to archive what you want:

If you really want to use Mobile_Detect you can do something like this:

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if($detect->isMobile()){ /* include mobile.css */ } 
else if($detect->isTablet()){ /* include "tablet.css" */ }
else { /* include "desktop.css" */ }
```

But in my mind there is no need to use PHP in this case. You don't need to know WHAT kind of device the user is using since the styling issues are usually related to the screen dimensions. In CSS you can use Media Querys like this:

```
@media (min-width:320px) { /* smartphones, portrait iPhone */ }
@media (min-width:480px) { /* smartphones, landscape iPhone */ }
@media (min-width:600px) { /* portrait tablets */ }
@media (min-width:801px) { /* landscape tablets */ }
@media (min-width:1025px) { /* laptops, and desktops */ }
@media (min-width:1281px) { /* large laptops and desktops */ }
```

Inside the querys you can overwrite CSS properties that are only used if the screen dimension is in the given range. A very smart solution I think!

Comment: I totally agree, but for the responsiveness, what attributes are the most affected? Because when the screen sizes change, the whole layout has to change.

Comment: Well you can do all layout changes you want with the media queries. Since you only need to set the differences to the initial CSS definitions you don't need duplicate definitions in here.

Try to use percentage width - that makes everything much easier and you don't need a thousand queries for every single screen width ;)

Comment: For example Twitter Bootstrap uses a grid-system based on media querys which works very well. You may want to take a look at their codes. (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: It makes sense. Truly speaking, do have a demo in particular that has the editing done for the responsiveness?

Comment: Wait, when I use bootstrap, will I need to restructure the whole form?

Comment: You won't. Bootstrap only adds definitions for different elements/classes. If you don't use them your code won't be affected. If you want to use the responsive grid layout you need to set some classes to your divs. Take a look at the docs and the examples (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

But Bootstrap was only an example to see how others archive this. You can write this codes for your self very easy ;)

Comment: I have found how to create a form using bootstrap [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.htm)